# Popen subprocess OSError: [Error 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pantheon

I'm running pantheon locally, and has met such a problem in Linux. An error occurs that in subprocess.py raise child_exception. Is their any solution to this problem? The file tunnel_manager.py is like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


if cmd[2] == 'mm-tunnelclient' or cmd[2] == 'mm-tunnelserver':

            # expand home directory
            for i in xrange(len(cmd_to_run)):
                if ('--ingress-log' in cmd_to_run[i] or
                    '--egress-log' in cmd_to_run[i]):
                    t = cmd_to_run[i].split('=')
                    cmd_to_run[i] = t[0] + '=' + path.expanduser(t[1])

            procs[tun_id] = Popen(cmd_to_run, stdin=PIPE,
                                  stdout=PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

Comment: What's the value of `cmd_to_run`?

Comment: Try using the full pathname to the program you're running.

Answer (score 0):

mm-tunnelclient, mm-tunnelserver is not installed or not in your bash PATH variable. compile them and add them to the PATH variable.